# How do I make the x-coordinates letters?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have made a line graph in python with pyplot/matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

alphabet = range(0, 25)
firstLine = [letter + 65 for letter in alphabet]
secondLine = [letter + 97 for letter in alphabet]

plt.plot(alphabet, firstLine, '-b', label='ASCII value of capital.')
plt.plot(alphabet, secondLine, '--g', label='ASCII value of lowercase.')
plt.xlabel('Letter in Alphabet')
plt.ylabel('ASCII Value')
plt.title('ASCII value vs. Letter')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

On my x-axis, it current scales by numbers. However, I want increments on the x-axis to be labeled by letters (a, b, c, d) instead of say 0, 5, 10... Specifically, I want the letter 'a' to map to 0, 'b' to map to 1, etc.

How do I make pyplot do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `xticks` function.  If you do `pyplot.xticks([0, 1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])` then it will have axis marks at 0, 1, 2, and 3, and they will be labeled a, b, c, and d.  You can also use `np.arange` to quickly create the range of numbers you want.

Comment: Thanks! `pyplot.xticks(np.arange(0, 26), string.lowercase)` works!

Answer (score 6):

I've used `plt.xticks(range(26), [chr(97 + x) for x in xrange(26)])` below.

***NOTE:***  you should change your `alphabet = range(0, 25)` to `alphabet = range(26)` because otherwise you are missing out on 'z'.

[image]